# Why git simply erases my commit if I switch back to a commit instead of master?

Tags: git

Git is supposed to be a tool for easily switching back to test things and then getting back to what you were doing. Sometimes I switch back to an old commit by doing

```
git checkout old_commit_id
```

then to get back I do

```
git checkout latest_commit_I_did
```

and start doing work. Then I commit this work.

```
git commit -m "did some work"
```

Then I go back to another commit with

```
git checkout another_old_commit_id
```

Then my commit `did some work` is simply LOST forever. Why it's so easy to lose a ton of work on git? Since `git checkout latest_commit_I_did` is the last commit I did, why it simply not added my commit on top of this one?

I think it has something to do with it not knowing in which branch I am but it should, **at least** warn me. Why simply delete everything I did with no warnings? I've already lost some important works because of this.

Comment: 1. Can you clarify why you are switching between commits? 2. You didn't lose anything, it's all accessible in the reflog: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: @JBallin I'm switching just to see how the code was before and then go back

Comment: @JBallin I found this `bc492f1 HEAD@{17}: commit: backup` on doing `git reflow show`. I think it's the commit I lost, how do I recover?

Comment: Your new commit is still there, not lost. Either `git checkout your_branch` if the commit was made on one or `git checkout your_latest_commit_id` which would always work.

Comment: ok, I fixed by ding `git reset --hard id_found_on_git_reflow` but I do not have any idea of whats going on. The commit that I lost was made when I was on `latest_commit_id`. Then I've gone to `old_random_commit`  then did `git checkout master` and the commit was gone. Why this happens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+recover+detached+HEAD+commits

Answer (score 0):

The commit isn't lost, it just takes you back in time to the previous commit. To come back to the latest commit just enter `git checkout master` or the name of your branch and you will be back to your latest commit.

Comment: this is not what happens. If I checkout back to the latest commit (NOT `git checkout master`, but instead `git checkout latest_commit`) and edit something and `git commit -m "this commit will go away"`, then if I `git checkout random_old_commit` and then `git checkout master`, then `this commit will go away` really gone away

Comment: Try checking back to the branch instead of checking out to the latest commit